# What is the decision function used in sklearn's SVM

Tags: scikit-learn

I am struggling to find out the decision function used in sklearn's svm for decision function type ovr.
Is anyone able to help me out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)? That article talks about some decision functions.

Comment: @nbro that was actually really helpful, thanks!